# Определить, попадает ли координата в закрашенную область

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика

Уважаемые форумчане!
Нашел в интернете такую задачу : определить, попадает ли введенная координата `(X,Y)` в заштрихованную область.
**Мои догадки**
Введенная координата X должна быть в диапазоне `[-5,5]` и координата Y в диапазоне `[-1,1]`. *Но, тут есть окружность и как я думаю, нужно определять некую взаимосвязь между `X` и `Y`.*
Прошу помочь мне в решении этой задачи. Благодарю!

[image: График]

Comment: C++ ни при чём, это математика школьного уровня по школьным формулам прямой и окружности

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Введенная координата X должна быть в диапазоне [-5,5] и координата Y в
>   диапазоне [-1,1].

Данное наблюдение можно использовать, как предусловие для этой задачи. То есть если точка находится внутри прямоугольника, то **возможно** она попадает в заштрихованную область. Если точек много, то можно увеличить производительность откинув точно не попадающие.
[image: Ограничивающий примитив]

```
Point p;
// Каким-то образом получили точку и сохранили в p
if (abs(p.x) <= 5.0 && abs(p.y) <= 1.0) {
    // Проверяем попадает ли точка в заштрихованную область
} else {
    // Точка точно не попадает в заштрихованную область
}
```

Далее вам нужно определить в какой четверти лежит точка `p`. Если во второй и четвертой, то нужно проверить попадает ли точка в окружность с радиусом 1. Для этого нужно подставить координаты точки в уравнение окружности `x^2 + y^2 < 1^2` (либо <= если  интересует и граница).

```
if (p.x * p.x + p.y * p.y <= 1.0) {
     // Точка попадает в окружность
}
```

Для первой четверти уравнение прямой `y = 1 - 0.2x`. Следовательно точка попадает в треугольник, если выполняются условия `p.x >= 0.0 && p.y >= 0.0 && p.y + 0.2 * p.x <= 1.0`. Но `p.x >= 0.0 && p.y >= 0.0` можно убрать, потому что это по сути есть проверка на принадлежность точки к первой четверти.

Для третьей четверти все аналогично, но можно заметить, что треугольники похожи. Следовательно можно упростить проверку до вот такого вида:

```
// Работает для 1 и 3 четверти
if (abs(p.y) + 0.2 * abs(p.x) <= 1.0) {
     // Точка попадает в треугольник
}
```

Собрав все вместе получаем:

```
Point p;
// Каким-то образом получили точку и сохранили в p
if (abs(p.x) <= 5.0 && abs(p.y) <= 1.0) {
    // Проверяем попадает ли точка в заштрихованную область
    if ((/*Точка в 2 или 4 четверти?*/) && p.x * p.x + p.y * p.y <= 1.0) {
        // Точка попадает в окружность
    } else if ((/*Точка в 1 или 3 четверти?*/) && abs(p.y) + 0.2 * abs(p.x) <= 1.0) {
        // Точка попадает в треугольник
    } else {
        // Точка не попадает в заштрихованную область.
    }
} else {
    // Точка точно не попадает в заштрихованную область
}
```

P.S. Для таких задач лучше добавлять метки *Математика*, *Геометрия* и тп.

Answer (score 0):

В начале надо узнать, какая у нас четверть. Например : при x > 0 && y > 0 - первая, и т.д. Затем, в 2 и 4 четвертях, у нас круг с радиусом 1 , и центром в начале координат. Что бы точка входила в неё, мы проверяем условие (x^2 + y^2 <= 1 ). Если да - то точка входит в этот круг. Для 1 четверти у нас график y = -x/5 + 1; Т.e  ( y + x/5 <= 1 ) - входит. А для 3 - ( y + x/5 >= -1) - входит. Вроде так.